# I have an object. I need to print its name as <option> on an <selector> but return another variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have an object:

```
company: {
  name: 'Google',
  id: '123asd890jio345mcn',
}
```

I need to print its name as an option of material-ui selector (Autocomplete rendering TextField)

But when user clicks on it, i need to return it's ID to an State or something else, so I can use it later.

```
return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="company"
      open={open}
      onOpen={() => {
        setOpen(true);
      }}
      onClose={() => {
        setOpen(false);
      }}
      loadingText="Buscando empresas..."
      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.id}
      renderOption={(props, option) => (
        <Box component="li" {...props}>
          {option.name}
        </Box>
      )}
      options={options}
      loading={loading}
      noOptionsText="Nenhuma empresa cadastrada"
      defaultValue={data.company}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...register("company")}
          {...params}
          label="Empresa"
          placeholder="Selecione a empresa"
          InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            endAdornment: (
              <React.Fragment>
                {loading ? (
                  <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} />
                ) : null}
                {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
              </React.Fragment>
            ),
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[With that configuration, when user clicks on any option it retrieves it's ID as value, but I want to show the name on the input instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMZgs.png)

I've tried a lot. But the only argument I can retrieve from this Autocomplete is it's current value, which is ID OR name. I can't show the name and retrieve the ID.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `onChange`? You can get the entire object from onChange second argument, value. I've made a simplified version here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-repl-forked-nqv8pw?file=/src/index.js:464-504

```
<Autocomplete
  // your other props
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
  onChange={(_, value) => console.log(value)}
  // your other props
/>
```

Comment: That's it! Then I can store the company ID on a state using onChange second argument. Perfect! Thank you!